# Un-hardcode deploy config image tag name

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-3

Right now our DC (deployment config) has this hardcoded it it:

/// dc.yaml

```
 image: containers.nabisco.com/cdt-org/cdt-dev:latest
```

then we roll out the dc with:

```
$ oc rollout latest dc/cdtcae-prod-deployment
```

however one problem I am noticing is that sometimes the "latest" tag refers to an old one and the newer one doesn't get pulled in - might be a bug with OpenShift or Kubernetes or what not.

we want to use git commit hashes to uniquely identify deployments, for the moment.

My question is - is there a way to override / update the image: line above, using the command line, so this line:

```
 image: containers.nabisco.com/cdt-org/cdt-dev:latest
```

would get overriden by something like this:

```
oc rollout --tag="$my_git_commit_hash" dc/cdtcae-prod-deployment
```

Comment: `image: containers.nabisco.com/cdt-org/cdt-dev:__TAG__`  and then `sed -i 's/__TAG__/$my_git_commit_hash/' dc.yaml && <rollout_command>`

Comment: yeah I knew there had to be right way to do this, that didn't involve what you rightly suggested. I added an answer, I think this is the way to do it.

Comment: There is the ``oc set image`` command. Bigger question is whether you are using an ``ImageStream`` and so also using a ``ImageChange`` trigger in the deployment configuration. Using these provides more flexibility on being able to update the image being used by a deployment, than the deployment configuration referencing an image in a remote registry directly.

Answer (score 0):

I heard that the best option would be to use the following setting in your yaml DC config:

```
 imagePullPolicy: "Always"
```

then you can just hard code some unique value

```
image: containers.nabisco.com/cdt-org/cdt-dev:foobarbaz
```

and it will always pull the latest one, instead of using the cache.